# How do you print the text to the next activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

This is on my main activity, after clicking the button it should show the message in the edit text view to the second activity. But for some reason it doesnt show the message I typed in the text view after hitting the button.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText  edtxt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextWord);
    }

    public void btnSend_onClick(View view) {
        String name = edtxt.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("Word", name);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share what the code looks like in your `MainActivity2` class?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Several ways you can do it.

`MainActivity2.class`

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView txtView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtWord);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String txt = intent.getStringExtra("Word");
        txtView.setText(txt);
    }
}
```